# How can I discover attached motor shields in code?

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I'm using the [Motor Shield v2](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/library-reference) and I'm looking for a way to automatically discover the addresses of attached motor shields.

Comment: research how to discover i2c devices

Answer (score 1):

If you configure each I2C device to have a unique address, then it's easy to determine which ones are connected.

This sketch is derived from the I2C Scanner sketch found here: [I2cScanner](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner)

```
// This sketch tests the standard 7-bit addresses.
// Devices with higher bit address might not be seen properly.
#include <Wire.h>
byte shieldOneAddress = 0x27;
byte shieldTwoAddress = 0x32;
byte error, address;

void setup(){

  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Scanning for shields...");

  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++){

    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();

    if(error == 0){
      if(address == shieldOneAddress){
        Serial.println("Shield One is connected.");
      }
      if(address == shieldTwoAddress){
        Serial.println("Shield Two is connected.");
      }
    }

  }
  Serial.println("Scan complete.\n");
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: This code detects a device connected at address 112. This is the [all call](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/faq#faq-10) address. It doesn't detect the individual address of a motor shield (0x60 in my case).

Comment: So ^that is true when the [motor shield library](http://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library/html/class_adafruit___motor_shield.html#a96e0da77dcc865279404ff48e42b55b7) isn't imported, but when the motor shield library is imported it works fine. Maybe they do some setup, not sure.